# How to view a linux file?

Tags: linux

I am attempting to view a file that has the following permissions

`-rw-r-xr--. 1 sjc25 domain users 1177 Apr 10 10:12 d_V_g_dt.f`

However, when I attempt to view the file using:

`more d_V_g_dt.f`,

I get the following message:

`d_V_g_dt.f: Permission denied.`

I have also used the following commands: `cat`, `head`, `tail`, `tac`, `less`, `nano`, `pico`, `vi`, `emacs`

From what I see I should be able to at least read the file. http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs2211_moreno/notes/security-and-permissions.pdf

How would I be able to view the file? I don't need to edit it, just view it.

Comment: Have you run `sudo cat...`? Do you get the same result?

Comment: IIRC the period after the permissions block means that SELinux has something to say about this. Use `ls -Z` to find out what.